# jackson serialization for Java object with Map?

Tags: java, json, jackson

I have a Java class like this and want to convert to JSON using Jackson. Thanks for your help.

1. #### Java Class

   ```
   public class myClass {
      String Id;
      Map<String, Object> optionalData = new LinkedHashMap<String, Object>();
   }
   ```
2. #### How to serialization it to JSON using Jackson ObjectMapper ?

For example, suppose the `optionalData` is a Map saving two entries `<"type", "book">` and `<"year", "2014">`
I want the output to be as follow. Please note that the key/value of optionalData could be changed on the fly (so, I cannot create a "static" Java object for this without using Map)

```
  [ 
    { 
      id: "book-id1",
      type: "book",
      year: "2014"
    },
    { 
      id: "book-id2",
      type: "book",
      year: "2013"
     }
  ]
```

Comment: what you have tried so far? and where you facing problem? show some code.

Answer (score 2):

You can use the `@JsonAnyGetter` annotation on a getter method that returns the map of optional values. Please refer to [this blog plost](http://www.cowtowncoder.com/blog/archives/2011/07/entry_458.html) that explains that in details.

Here is an example:

```
public class JacksonAnyGetter {

    public static class myClass {
        final String Id;
        private final Map<String, Object> optionalData = new LinkedHashMap<>();

        public myClass(String id, String key1, Object value1, String key2, Object value2) {
            Id = id;
            optionalData.put(key1, value1);
            optionalData.put(key2, value2);
        }

        public String getid() {
            return Id;
        }

        @JsonAnyGetter
        public Map<String, Object> getOptionalData() {
            return optionalData;
        }
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) throws JsonProcessingException {
        ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();
        List<myClass> objects = Arrays.asList(
                new myClass("book-id1", "type", "book", "year", 2013),
                new myClass("book-id2", "type", "book", "year", 2014)
        );
        System.out.println(mapper.writerWithDefaultPrettyPrinter().writeValueAsString(objects));
    }

}
```

Output:

```
[ {
  "id" : "book-id1",
  "type" : "book",
  "year" : 2013
}, {
  "id" : "book-id2",
  "type" : "book",
  "year" : 2014
} ]
```

Comment: You can't however deserialize json back to object.

Answer (score 0):

You need to write your own [`Jackson JsonSerializer`](http://jackson.codehaus.org/1.7.3/javadoc/org/codehaus/jackson/map/JsonSerializer.html) to create custom JSON string from Java object as per the need.

Here are the nice posts along with example

- [JSON Serializer & DeserializerHow do I use a custom Serializer with Jackson?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7161638/how-do-i-use-a-custom-serializer-with-jackson)
- [How Do I Write a Jackson JSON Serializer & Deserializer?](http://dev.sghill.net/2012/04/how-do-i-write-jackson-json-serializer.html)

---

The same thing you can achieve using [`GSON JsonSerializer`](https://google-gson.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/gson/docs/javadocs/com/google/gson/JsonSerializer.html)

Here are some examples

- [Serialize java object with GSON](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11038553/serialize-java-object-with-gson)
- [GSON Serialiser Example - javacreed](http://www.javacreed.com/gson-serialiser-example/)

---

Here is the code using `GSON Serialiser`

```
List<MyClass> list = new ArrayList<MyClass>();

MyClass myClass1 = new MyClass();
myClass1.setId("book-id1");
myClass1.getOptionalData().put("type", "book");
myClass1.getOptionalData().put("year", "2014");
list.add(myClass1);

MyClass myClass2 = new MyClass();
myClass2.setId("book-id2");
myClass2.getOptionalData().put("type", "book");
myClass2.getOptionalData().put("year", "2013");
list.add(myClass2);

class MyClassSerialiser implements JsonSerializer<MyClass> {

    @Override
    public JsonElement serialize(final MyClass obj, final Type typeOfSrc,
            final JsonSerializationContext context) {
        final JsonObject jsonObject = new JsonObject();

        jsonObject.addProperty("id", obj.getId());
        Map<String, String> optioanlData = obj.getOptionalData();
        if (optioanlData.size() > 0) {
            for (Map.Entry<String, String> entry : optioanlData.entrySet()) {
                jsonObject.addProperty(entry.getKey(), entry.getValue());
            }
        }

        return jsonObject;
    }
}

String jsonString = new GsonBuilder().setPrettyPrinting().
        .registerTypeAdapter(MyClass.class, new MyClassSerialiser()).create()
        .toJson(list);

System.out.println(jsonString);
```

output:

```
[
    {
        "id": "book-id1",
        "type": "book",
        "year": "2014"
    },
    {
        "id": "book-id2",
        "type": "book",
        "year": "2013"
    }
]
```