# Nested Jackson Serialisation

Tags: java, json, jackson

I have question about custom json serialisation with jackson. I know about the Custom Serializers, but I want to ask if there is an existing Serializer for solving my problem. The JSON I want to create looks like this.

```
{
"propertiesObject" : {
"properties":[
      {
         "key":"key",
         "value":"Array[value]"
      }
     ...
```

The Java Class would look like this example

```
public class Item {
    String key= "value";
```

As I mentioned before, I know about the Custom Serializer Implementation, would solve the problem, but do you know an Jackson Seriliser, which does this kind of Serialisation.

Comment: this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25375979/jackson-serialization-for-java-object-with-map should help

Comment: There is no predefines serialiser which would generate `JSON` payload like you want from given class. You have to implement custom serialiser in this case.

Comment: Thanks. Good to know.