# Object serialization to json, certain fields only

Tags: java, json, serialization

I have a large nested object. I want to serialise this object in the JSON string, however I need only certain fields to be included. Problem here is that fields could change very frequently and I want to build it in a way that could help me easy include or exclude fields for serialisation.

I know that I can write a lot of code to extract certain fields and build JSON "manually". But I wonder if there are any other elegant way to achieve similar outcome but specifying a list of required fields?

For example having following object structure I want include only `id` and `name` in the response:

```
class Building {
    private List<Flat> flats;
}

class Flat {
    private Integer id;     
    private Person owner;
}


class Person {
    private String name;
    private String surname;
}
```

Json:

```
{
    "flats" : [
        {
            "flat":
            {
                "id" : "1",
                "person" : {
                    "name" : "John"
                }
            }
        }
    ]
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [`gson`](https://github.com/google/gson) for serializing/deserializing `JSON`.
Then you can include the [`@Expose`](https://static.javadoc.io/com.google.code.gson/gson/2.6.2/com/google/gson/annotations/Expose.html) annotation to use only the fields you require.

Be sure to also configure your `Gson` object to only serialize "exposed" fields.

```
Gson gson = GsonBuilder().excludeFieldsWithoutExposeAnnotation().create();
```

**Alternative:**

You can actually do it the inverse way, marking fields which will not be *exposed*. You can do this with the [`transient`](https://www.javatpoint.com/transient-keyword) keyword.
So whatever you want to ignore just add `transient` to it. Here's how it works on [`gson`](https://sites.google.com/site/gson/gson-user-guide#TOC-Finer-Points-with-Objects).

PS: This works on most Java `JSON` serializers too.

Comment: Sounds great, I will try that! In case I mark entire private Person owner field as @Expose will it automatically include all nested fields as well?

Comment: Actually you have to mark all fields with the `@Expose` annotation if you want them serialized. I edited the answer with an alternative, read that too, maybe that is better suited for you.

Answer (score 0):

Using `com.fasterxml.jackson.annotation.JsonIgnore` is another way to achieve this.

```
import com.fasterxml.jackson.annotation.JsonIgnore;

class Person {
    private String name;
    @JsonIgnore
    private String surname;
}
```

It will ignore the `surname` when the parser converts the bean to json.
Similar annotation will be available in other json processing libraries.

Answer (score 0):

If using Gson, study how to use ExclusionStrategy & JsonSerializer.

Using those is a more flexible way to control serialization since it allows to decide per serialization what to serialize.

Using annotations requires later to add / remove those annotations from fields if there is a need to change what to serialize.

In the case of your example the latter might be more appropriate.

This question might be good startpoint
[serialize-java-object-with-gson](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11038553/serialize-java-object-with-gson#11038888)